# where to ask basic grammar related questions on SE?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am trying to learn grammar rules and was practicing couple of questions from my book, but unsure about my answers, where can I ask them? There are 5-6 questions, should I ask in one single post or in different posts along with my explanation?

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English or not?

Comment: no @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica, I am not

Answer (score 4):

Always ask only 1 question per question. If it is a certain grammar rule you don't understand which comes with 6 examples, you can put those six in a single post.

Seeing that you are learning English, [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) appears to be the site of choice. Be sure to check out their help centre though to see what exactly is [on topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, actually its a mixed exercise , so I'll rather club them into their respective groups and then ask it

Comment: Okay, be sure to spread them out to seperate questions then. And you might want to wait a bit in between asking them, so you can improve your questions based on feedback you get on your first question.